# Is it ok to let users scroll for more information on the main elements?

Tags: user-expectation, usability-testing, overflow

I know that your suppose to have the most important content and information in front view. In other words, users shouldn't have to scroll to get to the content. However, what about the content of those elements?

I have movies, on hover, a descriptive div appears:

[image: Visual Aid of Descriptive Div]

In this case, the descriptive div is easy to read and you don't have to scroll. However, what about this case?

[image: Visual Aid of End of Descriptive Div]

You can read the description of the movie, but you can't view all the other information (tags, year of movie, files left). **Is this important?** One thing to note is that it's easy to scroll and still stay on the movie and view the rest of the descriptive content.

Comment: One thing to note: The screenshot hides the mouse cursor. I'm hovering over the movies when the descriptive div appears...

Answer (score 1):

I find the hover disruptive. While on the second image would think that it's a a bug misplaced information.

I suggest you can place the information in another page. So that the user can get a better overview of the movie, if so he/she needs. You can place a button or a link for it.